# Size of UTF-8 string in bytes

Tags: c++, qt, utf-8

I am using QString to store strings, and now I need to store these strings (converted to UTF-8 encoding) in POD structures, which looks like this :

```
template < int N >
struct StringWrapper
{
  char theString[N];
};
```

To convert raw data from the QString, I do it like this :

```
QString str1( "abc" );
StringWrapper< 20 > str2;
strcpy( str2.theString, str1.toUtf8().constData() );
```

Now the question. I noticed that if I convert from normal string, it works fine :

```
QString str( "abc" );
std::cout<< std::string( str.toUtf8().constData() ) << std::endl;
```

will produce as the output :

```
abc
```

but if I use some special characters, like for example :

```
QString str( "Schöne Grüße" );
std::cout<< std::string( str.toUtf8().constData() ) << std::endl;
```

I get a garbage like this:

```
Gr\xC3\x83\xC2\xBC\xC3\x83\xC2\x9F
```

I am obviously missing something, but what exactly is wrong?

---

**ADDITIONAL QUESTION**

What is a maximum size of an UTF-8 encoded character? I read it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) it is 4 bytes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first question you need to answer is what is the encoding of your source files is? QString default constructor assumes it's Latin1 unless you change it with QTextStream::setCodecForCStrings(). So if your sources are in anything else than Latin1 (say, UTF-8), you get a wrong result at this point:

```
QString str( "Schöne Grüße" );
```

Now, if your sources are in UTF-8, you need to replace it with:

```
QString str = QString::fromUtf8( "Schöne Grüße" );
```

Or, better yet, use QObject::trUf8() wherever possible as it gives you i18n capabilities as a free bonus.

The next thing to check is what is the encoding of your console is. You try to print a UTF-8 string to it, but does it support UTF-8? If it's a Windows console, it probably doesn't. If it's something xterm-compatible using a Unicode font on a *nix system with some *.UTF-8 locale, it should be fine.

**To your edited question:**

I don't see any reason not to trust Wikipedia, especially when it refers to a particular standard. It also mentions that UTF-8 used to have up to 6 bytes characters, though. From my experience, 3 bytes is maximum you get with reasonable native language characters like Latin/Cyrillic/Hebrew/Chinese/Japanese. 4 bytes are probably used for something much more exotic, you can always check the standards if you are really curious.

Comment: QString str( L"Schöne Grüße" ); looks like an easier fix.

Comment: @MSalters, wow it's the first time I hear about wide character string literals. Still, it's not guaranteed to use any particular encoding in the general case (and how it interprets actual bytes in the literal?), and besides, QString has no constructor accepting wchar_t*, so it would be `QString str = QString::fromWCharArray(L"Schöne Grüße");` - not quite easier now?

Comment: Hmm, that's remarkably stupid by Trolltech standards. As for the "no encoding guaranteed", at least the encoding of `wchar_t` is fixed at compile time instead of depending on locale. But yeah, looks like a case for `#define QSTR(x) QString::fromWCharArray(L##x)`

Comment: @MSalters, it is fixed at compile time, but how would you guarantee that it is correct? Surely the compiler needs to convert from whatever encoding your sources is in to wchar_t (whatever that is on a particular platform). The problem is, how would it know which encoding your sources use? It could use local encoding or it could try to detect UTF-8 or whatever. Then again, using QString() or QString::fromUtf8() is _not_ locale-dependent. The only locale-dependent way to construct a QString is QString::fromLocal8Bit() which you usually want to use for external input only.

Comment: @SergeyTachenov: From wikipedia "The original specification covered numbers up to 31 bits (the original limit of the Universal Character Set). In November 2003 UTF-8 was restricted by RFC 3629 to end at U+10FFFF, in order to match the constraints of the UTF-16 character encoding. This removed all 5- and 6-byte sequences, and about half of the 4-byte sequences."

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that goes wrong is your stated assumption. `QString` doesn't store UTF-8, it stores unicode strings. That's why you need to call `str1.toUtf8()`. It creates a temporary UTF-8 string.

The second part is just how UTF-8 works. It's a multi-byte extension of ASCII. `üß` aren't ASCII characters, and you do expect that both characters get a multi-byte representation. `std::cout` apparently doesn't expect UTF-8. This depends on the `std::locale` used.

Comment: Ok, fixed the first sentence. Thanks

Comment: About the 2nd part I expected to get a garbage instead of special letters

Comment: @VJo, you can't guarantee that. For example, one of the bytes representing "ö" could be interpreted by the console terminal as a special control character meaning "move the cursor to the start of the line" so the next characters would overwrite the previous ones. Or something even worse like switching terminal mode and making it completely unusable. Depends on a particular terminal used.