# QScintilla syntax highlighting with QsciLexerCustom - UTF-8 issue

Tags: c++, qt, scintilla, qscintilla

I'm using QScintilla as a text editor in my C++ Qt project and would like to have syntax highlighting for my custom(ish) language.

Following a great guide I found ([qscintilla](https://qscintilla.com/#syntax_highlighting)), I subclassed QsciLexerCustom and implemented all necessary methods, specifically `QsciLexerCustom::styleText`. All seems to be working great until I write a non-ASCII character in the editor, which makes the highlightight to be shifted.  After some investigation I found out the key is most likey in different character lengths of UTF8. This is the beginning of my styleText method:

```
void TemplateHighlighter::styleText(int start, int end)
{
    startStyling(start);

    const auto editor = qobject_cast<QsciScintilla*>(parent());
    mText = editor->text(start, end);
    mTextPos = 0;

    // do the work
}
```

Now for example, if the editor contains a non-ASCII text like `č-č-č`, the styleText method is called with `start == 0` and `end == 8`, because that's the size of the Scintilla UTF-8 buffer (3x 2B plus 2x 1B). But the QString I get from the editor for this range only has 5 characters. So when I style the whole string with `setStyling(5, Styles::Example)`, it's not enough, because that means I haven't styled everything I was asked for and at least the last `č` won't be styled.

I was trying to figure out a way around this but really don't see any reasonable options, if I want to stick with QStrings and don't want to work with the raw buffer, which would render my whole lexer implementation useless. Is there something I'm missing? Or some more or less reasonable workaround?

Comment: Possibly of interest:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826379/size-of-utf-8-string-in-bytes

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Thank you for the link, I've read through it and it doesn't look like my issue. The char[] buffer from which the QString is initialized has the correct sequence of UTF-8 bytes - `c4 8d 2d c4 8d 2d c4 8d`. It really looks like QsciLexerCustom just can't be used for lexing any text containing multibyte characters, much less variable sized UTF-8. :(

Comment: I take it calling `setStyling(8, Styles::Example);` wouldn't get you the desired result?

Comment: It would in this example and that's what I decided to do until I figure out something better (or go back to QPlainTextEdit) - for every piece of styled text, I get UTF buffer (with QStringRef::toUtf8) and call the setStyling method with the size of this buffer. That way I'm always styling the correct number of bytes. Not the most effective way, but at the moment I can't think of any better way of getting byte size of UTF-8 encoded string out of QString

Comment: It might be worthwhile to email QScintilla's author(s) and ask them if they have a recommended solution for this issue

Comment: Good idea, I'll give it a try. :)

Comment: Btw. I realized this has a rather simple solution, at least for my use case. Instead of using QString, I can take the UTF-8 buffer from Scintilla directly and create an std::string (or even std::string_view to save the extra copy) and work with that. That way I have 1:1 characters to bytes count and still can use regular expressions etc. This works fine, because I only need to analyze ASCII characters, the rest just needs to be styled properly, but it doesn't matter what value (even invalid) it has.